# ggplot2: show missing value colour in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, missing-data

Just wondering what is required so the colour for missing values is shown in the legend?
Looking at example from the UseR! ggplot2 book, p94

```
p <- qplot(sleep_total, sleep_cycle, data=msleep, colour=vore)
p + scale_colour_hue(na.value = "Black")
p +  scale_colour_hue("What does \nit eat?", na.value="Black", breaks=c("herbi", "carni", "omni", "insecti", NA), labels=c("plants", "meat", "both", "insects", "don't know"))
```

the data point for vore=NA is shown in the plot but NA is not listed in the legend.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for the problem would be to replace `NA` values in your data with same other character (for example, `unknown`) and plot data.

So, made new variable vore2 that has `vore` values as characters. Then replaced `NA` values with the `unknown`.

```
msleep$vore2<-as.character(msleep$vore)
msleep$vore2[is.na(msleep$vore2)]<-"unknown"
```

In the plot used new variable `vore2` for the colors.

```
p <- qplot(sleep_total, sleep_cycle, data=msleep, colour=vore2)
p +  scale_colour_hue("What does \nit eat?", 
            breaks=c("herbi", "carni", "omni", "insecti", "unknown"), 
                labels=c("plants", "meat", "both", "insects", "don't know"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I had gotten the impression from the textbook that a GGPlot2 setting would make this work so that such a work-around was not required, but perhaps not!