# removing missing values labels from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

what I want appears to be simple but I can't figure it out: I want to take the NA values from my labs out. Problem is, it's my first time using the "na.value" argument, so I’m not quite sure how to proceed.

(btw, I can’t drop the NAs before plotting because the shapes that are not from the tourist regions will also disappear, and I need the full map.)

I have this code:

```
mun_tur_shape %>% 
  filter(abbrev_state == "BA") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=TOURIST_REGION, colour=TOURIST_REGION)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    na.value = "grey90"
    values = c(viridis::inferno(13)),
    aesthetics = c("fill", "colour")
    ) +
    labs(fill = "Região Turística",
         colour = "Região Turística"
           ) +
```

And this is how it looks:
[Plot with NA value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZyzK.png)

Does anyone know what I can do to omit them?

```
# here's an sf for reproducible example:
#install.packages(geobr)
df <- geobr::read_state()

df %>%
  # creating NA values like my real dataset has
  mutate(name_region=case_when(name_region=="Nordeste"~NA_character_,
                          TRUE~name_region)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=name_region, colour=name_region)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    na.value = "grey90",
    values = (viridis::inferno(4)),
    aesthetics = c("fill", "colour")
  ) +
  labs(colour = "Regions",
       fill = "Regions")
```

Comment: Try using `na.translate = FALSE` inside `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: it also removes the grey area :(

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: ok, I added one now. (sorry, I'm new to the platform)

Comment: @BeatrizLeal Try adding `breaks` for specific regions to include, and make sure you have same number of `breaks` as `values`...maybe something like `breaks = unique(df$name_region), values = viridis::inferno(5)`...?

Comment: I think this may be a duplicated question, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932373/na-values-in-choropleth-plot-legend-with-ggplot2-in-r

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this (see also [NA values ​in choropleth plot legend with ggplot2 in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932373/na-values-in-choropleth-plot-legend-with-ggplot2-in-r)) is to add first a base layer with all the polygons (no aes) using the colors that I would want to use for `NA`. After that, you can overlay the layer with `aes()`. In practice, just add one line on your code

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(geobr)

df <- geobr::read_state()


df %>%
  # creating NA values like my real dataset has
  mutate(name_region = case_when(
    name_region == "Nordeste" ~ NA_character_,
    TRUE ~ name_region
  )) %>%
  # Create map
  ggplot() +
  # Add this line a base layer with no aes, but a NA fill color
  geom_sf(fill = "grey50", color = "grey50") +
  # end
  geom_sf(aes(fill = name_region, colour = name_region)) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    na.value = "grey90",
    values = (viridis::inferno(4)),
    aesthetics = c("fill", "colour"),
    na.translate = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(
    colour = "Regions",
    fill = "Regions"
  )
```

[image]